# Sending SMS using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sms, vb.net-2010

```
Dim message As New MailMessage()
message.To.Add("9999999999@ideacellular.net")
message.From = New MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com")
message.Subject = "Hi"
message.Body = "SMS"
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
smtp.EnableSsl = True
smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@gmail.com", "password")
smtp.Send(message)
```

I have written the above code in order to send SMS from my vb.net application to a Mobile phone.

When i execute this code i am not getting any errors, at the same time i am not receiving any SMS.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Your question headline says SMS, but your code shows email/smtp.

However, I don't see any port mention in your connection,and I seem to recall gmail smtp running on a specific port.

Comment: Hi Allan, I want to send SMS, which port number should i use??

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, probably you haven't read about this.... http://www.wirelessdevnet.com/channels/java/features/simplewire/ dont you?

Comment: @nandgate, your message title is in error.  You are, in fact, sending an SMTP e-mail above, not SMS.  Your end result may be SMS, but in fact the e-mail address you are sending to (@ideacellular.net) is relaying your e-mail to SMS.

Comment: [Send a Text Message to a Cell Phone from a VB.NET Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15299/Send-a-Text-Message-to-a-Cell-Phone-from-a-VB-NET)

Answer (score 2):

I have a perfect way to send SMS in visual basic.

Using AT-commands.

AT-commands:are instructed through which you can send and receive SMS messages,
and this is an example:

To Send a message

First:

Write this code in the top

```
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.IO
```

Secondly:

Write this code in the public class of form:

```
Dim SerialPort As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort()
Dim CR As String
```

Thirdly:

Create a textBox(TextmsgTextBox) to write the text message, and TextBox2(MobileNumberTextBox) to enter the mobile number, and Button(SendBUT) to Send message.

And write this code in the button click event.

```
If SerialPort.IsOpen Then
    SerialPort.Close()
End If
SerialPort.PortName = COM4
SerialPort.BaudRate = 9600
SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None
SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One
SerialPort.DataBits = 8
SerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend
SerialPort.DtrEnable = True
SerialPort.RtsEnable = True
SerialPort.NewLine = vbCrLf

Dim message As String
message = MsgRichTextBox.Text

Try
    SerialPort.Open()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("The modem with the port '" & SerialPort.PortName & "'is not plugged in!!" & vbcrlf & "Please plug the modem and try again.")
End Try

If SerialPort.IsOpen() Then
    SerialPort.Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
    SerialPort.Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
    SerialPort.Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & phoneNumBox.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
    SerialPort.Write(message & Chr(26))
    SentPicture.Visible = True
    SentLabel.Visible = True
    SentTimer.Start()
Else
    MsgBox("Port '" & SerialPort.PortName & "' is not available!")
End If
```

Comment: Hi Mousa, Thanks for the code. But i want to know what is the importance of this Port name ? and in my application what should be the port name ? Waiting for your reply.

Comment: I don't believe this will work - first of all, a serial port is local to the computer, and a physical port that is no longer used (obsoleted by USB, Firewire, Thunderbolt, and more).  Second, in order to send a SMS message, you need to connect to a service on the Internet; either a service for the carrier who operates the target phone, or an intermediary service that will relay your SMS to the proper carrier that operates the target device.

Comment: Hi There
You can also use mobile phone instead of Internet to send the message.
This mobile phone is connected to the computer via Bluetooth or usb cable.
and this is an example for a program that you can use it to send a message via internet or mobile phone : PuTTY - Link to download :  (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)
Thanks for comment.

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily I'm using the exact code you are using but mine does not send SMS but also with no errors...

My Ports are :

COM5 (ZTE NMEA Device) &
COM4 (ZTE Diagnostics Interface)...

I am currently using COM4 because when I use COM5 I am having an error which says 'Resource already been used'

Comment: @LuciferRodstark Some companies blocks AT-commands out of security or caution, since you as a programmer can do some bad stuff with it, so for example, the device i used in the images above (Nokia C2) worked for both sending and receiving SMSs, so the solution for that is to buy a USB 3G modem that supports AT-commands, also in this way you are not wasting all the phone functionality just for sending messages, here is some 3G modems that support AT-commands : [https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/gsm-modem-support-at-command.html](https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/gsm-modem-support-at-command.html)

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily I have another 3G USB Modem that supports AT-commands but it’s only available on Windows 7 because when I try to put the USB 3G Modem to my PC which has Windows 10 Pro the ports are not detected... Are there USB 3G Modems that still work on Windows 10?

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily do you also have a code if the Port Name doesn’t exist so it doesn’t show an error ‘COM8 does not exist’ if the modem is not plugged in and the program is running... So it just shows like a message box to plug the modem so that it will not interrupt the running of the program

Comment: @LuciferRodstark Unfortunately i don't know modems that supports Windows 10, you earthier have to find the Windows 10 driver for you current modem and install it, or search for a modem that supports Windows 10, also, i updated my code above to inform the user if the modem is not plugged in! Hope it helped :)

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily can you help me with my SMS problem.. It now sends SMS message but when there are 2 or more rows to read using the SQL Query it does not send any SMS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814095/sms-code-cant-send-bulk-messages-using-reader-read-loop-and-at-commands-vb-net

Answer (score 1):

Simple Send SMS using VB.NET + AT Command :

```
        Try
            With SerialPort1
                .Write("at+cmgf=1" & vbCrLf)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                .Write("at+cmgs=" & Chr(34) & TextBox1.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                .Write(TextBox2.Text & Chr(26))
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Port name change from time to another and from computer to another.

I will show you the way by pictures.

1:Enter to Device Manager from Control Panel.

[image]

2:Right click on the device, and choose Properties.
[image]

3:Choose Modem tap, and look for port name, and use it in your application.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable
        CreateDataTable(dt, "select * from Table where Id = 1")
        If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
            Dim request As HttpWebRequest
            Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
            Dim url As String
            Dim senderid As String = dt.Rows(0).Item("SenderId").ToString()
            Dim password As String = dt.Rows(0).Item("Password").ToString()
            Dim host As String
            Dim originator As String = dt.Rows(0).Item("UserName").ToString()
            Try
                host = "http://smsidea.co.in/sendsms.aspx?"
                'originator = "3423434343"
                'password = "234hj"
                url = host + "mobile=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(originator) _
                         & "&pass=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password) _
                         & "&senderid=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(senderid) _
                         & "&to=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(StrToNumber) _
                         & "&msg=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(StrBody)
                request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
                response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
                'MessageBox.Show("Response: " & response.StatusDescription)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Vb.net code for send sms.

Try

```
        Dim url As String

        'paste your sms api code to url

        'url = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/SMS_API/sendsms.php?username=XXXX&password=XXXXX&mobile=" + mobile + "&sendername=XXXX&message=XXXXX&routetype=1"


        url="Paste your api code"



        Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(myReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim respStreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream())
        Dim responseString As String = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
        respStreamReader.Close()
        myResp.Close()
        MsgBox("ok")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

http://yii2ideas.blogspot.in/2017/11/how-to-send-sms-from-vb-net-application.html