# Is it possible to send an SMS from Visual Basic 2013 through my smartphone?

Tags: android, vb.net, vba, sms

I would like to send an SMS from a VB2013 application with my smartphone programmatically. I have already found several solutions how to solve this with Windows Phone (Outlook-Windows Phone). The only problem is, that I have an android device. So my question is, do you know any idea or solution that supports android?

The workflow that I want to implement is the following:

- The user types into a textbox the phone number and the text on a VB2013 app.
- He/She clicks to the "Send" button, and somehow it sends an SMS from the android phone to the phone number that is given by himself/herself.

Regards,

Roland

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is not possible directly.

The problem you already found is that your Smartphone is Android and
Vb.Net needs a .net Framework with which it works.

So the possibility I see is to get a connection
via USB port to your device and send some specific commands to
make your smartphone send SMS. To do this you have to use a serial port from
my point of view.

This question has already been asked, so
please take a look at:

[Sending SMS with Vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131761/sending-sms-using-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

The .Net framework does not natively run on Android, so no this is not possible.

**However,** the [Xamarin](https://xamarin.com) framework allows you to write android apps in Visual Studio.

Specifically towards your question, Xamarin has an SmsManager class that allows you to send Sms messages, the documentation can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/networking/sms/send_an_sms/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to do this, but the best one is use an api like [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com).  You can literally send an sms with one line of code. They have a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio/) which would get you up and running even faster.

Another is to use carrier mail.  You have to know the users carrier and then you can create an email address that sends as a text ie. 1231234123@txt.att.net.  The issue with using cellular carrier email  is that spammers often use this and one minute there is a message from your site and then next is spam, since it will be coming from the same carrier.email address.